# PHP code doesn't upload name file into SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have some problems when I upload a picture, it uploads to the directory but in SQL it doesn't put the name, only puts 1 or 0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxSaO.jpg

In SQL, it's all in varchar(255).

```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $date=date("d/m/Y");

$target_dir = "../img/logo/";

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])){

    $insert=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE logo SET img = '".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."' AND  data_insercao = '".$date."'") or die("Error".mysqli_error());
    echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='index.php?pg=3'\" /> ";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='index.php?pg=3'\" /> ";
  }
}
```

***SOLVED***

What I did to change

```
$insert=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE logo SET img = '".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."', data_insercao = '".$date."'") or die("Error".mysqli_error());
```

Just had a comma instead of AND

Comment: be sure to that the variable type in DB of column 'img'  is VAR_CHAR and not INT

Comment: I already did @CamiloGo, It's in the post

Comment: Try switching `AND` for `, ` in your query. You could also build your query first, then `echo` it for testing purposes, then execute it.

Comment: @justbaron Thank you! Never thought it would be so easy to do.

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho added answer, feel free to accept and up-vote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch `AND` for `,` in your query.

```
$insert=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE logo SET img = '".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."',  data_insercao = '".$date."'") or die("Error".mysqli_error());
```

Presumably, you are using this table for one image, hence no need for a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help:

```
$insert=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE logo SET img = '".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]."', date = '$date'") or die("Error".mysqli_error());
```

p/s: You might want to put WHERE, just for reminder

Answer (score 0):

To update multiple columns use `,` instead of `AND`

```
 $insert=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE logo SET img = '".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."' , data_insercao = '".$date."'") or die("Error".mysqli_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
    $date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

    $target_dir = "../img/logo/";

      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])){

        $insert=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE logo SET img = '".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]."', date = '$date'") or die("Error".mysqli_error());
        echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='index.php?pg=3'\" /> ";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='index.php?pg=3'\" /> ";
      }
    }
```

use date time with second because sum time file name is same and date also so file will overwrite in image folder.